# Http post request ignoring piped delay

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, delay, rxjs-pipeable-operators

In my service class I'm firing post request like this

```
// my-service.service.ts
sendRequest(
    param: string
  ): Observable<HttpResponse<string>> {
    return this.http.post<HttpResponse<string>>("", {
      param
    }).pipe(
      retry(3),
    )
}
```

Thus the component is subscribing to the returned `Observable` by

```
// my-component.ts
this.myService.sendRequest(
      ""
    ).subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res)
      },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log(err.message)
      }
)
```

As you notice I'm doing post requests to `""` that is converted into `http://localhost:4200` that doesn't exist, so every post request will result in a `Cannot POST /` response (404).

I'm not getting why by adding a delay at

```
this.myService.sendRequest(
      ""
    ).pipe(delay(10000)).subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res)
      },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log(err.message)
      }
)
```

will cause the error response to ignore it and print on the console as long as the request completes thus ignoring it.

Comment: What outcome are you trying to achieve? That the subscriber doesn't print to `console.log` when your POST request returns a 404?

Comment: Unlike `catchError`, `retry`, `retryWhen` operators, `delay` is only triggered when the source observable emits a `next` notification. In case of `error` notifications, `delay` is completely ignored. Your question is akin to doing `this.myService.sendRequest('valid url')` and asking why the `retry(3)` isn't triggered. `retry` is only triggered on `error` notifications from the source observable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`delay` only delays emissions, not errors.

I opened a discussion some time ago in the rxjs' repo -> https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/discussions/6519

I think the only way of achieving what you want would be something like:

```js
this.myService.sendRequest(
  ""
).pipe(
  delay(10000),
  catchError(err => timer(10000).pipe(
    switchMap(() => throwError(() => err))
  ))
)
```

If you think that's ugly, you can always encapsulate it in a custom operator:

```js
const delayEverything = <T>(ms: number) => (source: Observable<T>) =>
  source.pipe(
    delay(ms),
    catchError(err => timer(ms).pipe(switchMap(() => throwError(() => err))))
  )

// ... and then use it as a regular operator

this.myService.sendRequest('').pipe(
  delayEverything(10000)
)
```